# Laravel Radius of latitude & longitude

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to find all postcodes within X radius of `{lat}/{long}`, however I am receiving a `TypeError`.

I'm getting this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Transformers\PostcodesTransformer::transform()  must be an instance of App\Postcodes, instance of stdClass given, called in /home/vagrant/postcode-data/vendor/league/fractal/src/Scope.php on line 338

The query is:

```
$postcodes = DB::select("Select 
    id, 
    postcode, 
    latitude, 
    longitude, 
    district, 
    postal_town, 
    county, 
    country, 
    northing, 
    easting, 
    type,
    acos(sin(".$lat.")*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(".$lat.")*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-".$lon.")) * ".$R." As distance
        From (
            Select *
            From uk_postcodes
            Where latitude Between ".$minLat." And ".$maxLat."
              And longitude Between ".$minLon." And ".$maxLon."
        ) As FirstCut
        Where acos(sin(".$lat.")*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(".$lat.")*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-".$lon.")) * ".$R."< ".$rad."
        Order by distance");
    return $this->response->withCollection($postcodes, new PostcodesTransformer);
```

However the result of the `DB::select` query returns `stdClass`.

How would I have it return an instance of the `Postcodes` class?

Answer (score 1):

There are possible two answers here.  The first is what I'd consider the wrong way but it's a more direct answer to your question.

We need to get this query using Eloquent somehow but in order to handle the table, we'd need to select from the postcodes table first, convert your query to use a temporary table.

```
DB::query("
    Create Temporary Table FirstCut Select *
    From uk_postcodes
    Where latitude Between ".$minLat." And ".$maxLat."
    And longitude Between ".$minLon." And ".$maxLon
);
```

And now we can join that with the your `postcodes` table using your model.  We have to start with the model because that's the only way to return instances of `App\Postcodes`

```
Postcodes::join('FirstCut', 'FirstCut.zipcode', '=', 'postcodes.zipcode') // Guessing column names here
    ->selectRaw('id, postcode, latitude, longitude, district, postal_town, county, country, northing, easting, type,
         acos(sin(".$lat.")*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(".$lat.")*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-".$lon.")) * ".$R." As distance'
    )
    ->whereRaw("acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-$lon)) * $R< $rad")
    ->orderByRaw('distance')
    ->get();
```

The second way to handle this would be abstracting logic out of `PostcodeTransformers`, create a new one which uses that logic, and can also handle `stdClass`.  Then all you need to do is pass your new `StdClassTransformer` in instead of `PostcodesTransformer`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you aren't using Laravel' Eloquent Model concept to make the queries to the Database.

Read about: [**Eloquent: Getting Started**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent).

So you can have a collection of Postcode objects like this:

Create a model named `Postcode` like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Postcode extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'postcodes';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Then while creating your query, you can do it like this, you can use Laravel's query builder's method - [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectRaw):

```
$postcodes = Postcode::selectRaw("
    *,
    acos(sin(".$lat.")*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(".$lat.")*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-".$lon.")) * ".$R." As distance
        From (
            Select *
            From uk_postcodes
            Where latitude Between ".$minLat." And ".$maxLat."
              And longitude Between ".$minLon." And ".$maxLon."
        ) As FirstCut
        Where acos(sin(".$lat.")*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(".$lat.")*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-".$lon.")) * ".$R."< ".$rad."
")
->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
->get();
```

You'll now get a collection of `Postcode` model Objects instead of `StdClass`. It would be better if you break your select raw query more deeply, as it seems to me that it will not work!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Saumya. Unfortunately that hasn't worked, as it's performing a double `from` query. http://pastebin.com/xkBFP82t

Comment: Yeah, you should break this up into small pieces and try it out!

Comment: I already had a Postcodes model defined. I'm not entirely sure using `selectRaw()` is going to work for this. I need to perform a sub query for the `from`

Comment: You can give it a try, and let me know if its working?